# Catch onclick adsense event ?

Tags: javascript, adsense

I wan't to send an ajax request if the user clicked on adsense .
But because adsense code is in iframe I can't find a way to catch the onclick event .. any ideas plz ??!

Comment: I found a trick !! thx anyway

Comment: @Isaam: Care to share with us?

Comment: @IssamZoli Anyone know if this is possible yet?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that **you can't**. Since adsense is likely on another domain, most access to the inside of the iframe is cut off. This is a cross-domain security feature built into all modern browsers. You may be able to catch the click event on the iframe (haven't personally tried before), but it's not going to tell you anything about the inside of the iframe.

Comment: for example , can I catch location change in the iframe ??